# Conditions in "includes" in Activerecord

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

If I have a model called "Article" and another called "Comment", with each Article having zero or more Comments and each Comment having an associated user, how do I do the following:

Find all articles on the site and any comments that the given user has made

In SQL:

```
SELECT * FROM articles LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON articles.id = comments.article_id AND comments.user_id = 2
```

I have tried doing this:

```
Article.joins('LEFT OUTER JOIN comments ON articles.id = comments.article_id AND comments.user_id = 2)
```

The result here is that `result.first.comments` give me all the comments for the article. I can solve this by adding conditions to the last part, but then it won't be eager

Answer (score 2):

If you want all the comments made by a particular user and corresponding articles, this should work:

```
Comment.joins(:articles).where("comments.user_id" => 2).select("comments.*, articles.*")
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you try with `Article.joins(:comments).where("comments.user_id" => 2)`?

Look [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) for more info.

Comment: I have tried that actually. The problem is that each Articles "comments" association contains all the comments for the article. When I do `Article.joins(:comments).where("comments.user_id" => 2).first.comments` I get all the comments for the first article, rather than the ones made by the given user

Comment: However it seems as if a combination of `includes`and `joins`works.
`Article.includes(:comments).joins(:comments).where("comments.user_id" => 2)` seems to work?

Comment: Nope, false alarm. That will of course only get the articles the user has commented on...